# Nodejs / Express.js/ Body-parser Unit Test: How to come through middlewares to test the routing function

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, express, middleware

I have been working on this problem for several days but I couldn't find any solution.

For each of my function in the route class I have this 2 Middlewares

`index.js`

```
const browser = require('browser-detect');
const detectBrowser = (req,res,next) => {
    const result = browser(req.headers['user-agent']);
    console.log(result);
    if (result) {
       if (result.name === 'chrome') {
           console.log('Browser: '+result.name+ ' OK!');
           next();
       } else if (result.name=== 'firefox') {
           console.log('Browser: '+result.name+ ' OK!');
           next();
       } else {
           res.render('browser-response');
       }
    }
};
```

```
const redirectHome = (req,res,next) => {
    if(req.session.token && req.session.firstName && req.session.lastName) {
        if (!req.session.checked) {
            res.redirect('/term-of-service');
        }
        else {
            res.redirect('/index');
        }
    } else {
        next();
    }
};
```

and a simple function I want to test is:

```
router.get('/', detectBrowser, redirectHome, (req, res) => {
    res.render("login");
});
```

I plan to use Mocha and Supertest as frameworks to test the `router.get(/)` function, but couldn't find anyway to mock the browser and the variables of session (session.token, session.firstName, session.lastName, session.checked).

Does anyone have an idea about this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this question I already found out a work around solution.
For the middleware **detectBrowser** we just need to add

`} else if (result.name=== 'node') { next(); }`

because we are working in the node enviroment so those lines of code will make the test file pass through the middleware.

For the second middleware we just need to provide stubbing session information for the test. Below is an example :

```
const route = require ("../../routes/index");
const request = require("supertest");
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const chai = require('chai');
const expect = chai.expect;

//create app with valid credentials (not yet accept term of service )
let mockingLoggedIn;

//setup mocking session
mockingLoggedIn = express();
mockingLoggedIn.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));
mockingLoggedIn.set('view engine', 'ejs');
mockingLoggedIn.use(bodyParser.json());
mockingLoggedIn.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

// lets stub session middleware
mockingLoggedIn.use(function (req, res, next) {
    req.session = {};
    next();
});
//provide a fake login
mockingLoggedIn.get('*', function (req, res, next) {
    // and provide some accessToken value
    req.session.token = "test";
    req.session.firstName= 'test';
    req.session.lastName = 'test';
    req.session.checked = false;
    next()
});
mockingLoggedIn.use(route);
```

And in the test we just need to use that stubbed app to make request to the route. For example:

```
describe("Testing / route and /login route works", () => {
it('testing index route: GET / should return status 200 and render login site', 
(done)=> {
request(mockingLoggedIn) // request an app with stubbed credentials
.get("/")
.expect("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8")
.expect(200)
.end(function (err,res) {
expect(err).to.be.null;
done();
})
});
});
```

Hopefully this will help someone :)